# Twisted server information

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, twisted, ubuntu-14.04

Hey so i have a twisted server set up for my client server application. My twisted server is running on an amazon e2 instance.

currently my server prints information to a log file like

```
2014-11-18 05:34:47+0000 [twisted.protocols.tls.TLSMemoryBIOFactory] clients are  [<__main__.UpdateServer instance at 0x7fe244ff1xx4>]
2014-11-18 05:34:49+0000 [UpdateServer (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),0,11.11.11.11] Recieved command: SendMeAFile
2014-11-18 06:00:39+0000 [UpdateServer (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),0,11.11.11.11] sending file at path /a/file/path of size 3432kb
```

I would like an interface where it displays something like this

---

My server info

Clients connected: 1

listofclientips: 11.11.11.11

Total data sent to all clients: 3432kb

Commands received from clients:

11.11.11.11: command: SendMeAFile

Total data sent to each client:

11.11.11.11: 3432kb

---

What are my options if any? Do i need to write another script to analyze this log file or is there a pre made option to do this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no pre-existing tools for doing this kind of analysis.  There is [ongoing work](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/milestone/New%20Logging%20System) to make analysis of Twisted logfiles easier, but it is not done yet.

Comment: Thanks, so it is time to write a script to phrase the server logs :-D